# Set Zookeeper Node (znode) setting in HappyBase HBase client

Tags: python, hbase, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, happybase

I want to connect to a Kerberos **secured** HBase database via HappyBase (python).

The connection worked for another **unsecured** cluster with this settings:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection("host1.domain.de", port=9090)
connection.open()
print(connection.tables())
```

Now I want to connect to my secured database via the Zookeeper quorum (let's say `host2.domain.de`) and the port `2181`. The zookeper node is `/hbase-secured`

I try to connect to my db with the same code as shown above (after making a `kinit` via console). But I can't connect. It seems to be a problem with the changed `/hbase-secured` zookeeper node.

Is there a possibility to change this zookeeper node setting? Or can't HappyBase connect to a Kerberized cluster yet? Do I need to make the Kerberos settings in another way?

I'm using HBase 1.1.2 in a Hortonworks Data Platform 2.6 environment, trying to connect with HappyBase 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported.

In https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#connection

> The host and port arguments specify the host name and TCP port of the **HBase Thrift server** to connect to.